# Cannot find my test actions on google service on google home on my android?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

Google home listed my test service under my account so I can test it without publish the service. Today I unlinked my test service and tried to link again, but now I could not my test service.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that

- You've enabled testing recently. You may need to explicitly disable and re-enable testing.
- You're logged in with the same account
- Check things like the invocation name to be sure you're seeing the expected name in the Home app